# Пытаюсь залить в circle картинку. И она заливается, но есть проблема.(смотр. на картинке). Circle не зафиксирован точными координатами

Tags: javascript, svg

[image]

```
d3.select("#zoomEl").append('g').attr('id', 'g_circles').selectAll('circle').data(this.objectTree.getVertices()).enter()
  .append('circle').attr('cx', d => {
  return d.p.x;
}).attr('cy', d => {
  return d.p.y;
}).attr('fill', 'url(#picture)').attr('r', this.vRad);

d3.select("svg").append('svg:defs').append("svg:pattern")
  .attr("id", "picture").attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
  .attr('height', 56).attr('width', 56).append('svg:image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRfqQvGKkyN1GXhYEaA6wKcVNu_Hr-HnHPVwIHyhA6W5I7fBdL2A').attr('width', 56).attr('height', 56).attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0);
```

Comment: А где проблема?

Comment: Проблема что картинка не по центру

Comment: добавьте attr в pattern `preserveAspectRatio="none"` потом отпишитесь

Comment: @SashaRomanyshyn можно рабочий пример? Ссылочку на jsfiddle например

Comment: а зачем вообще пнг внутри svg ? тянуться не будет так какой смысл? просто круглая рамка у картинки не пойдет? переведите уж лучше саму картинку в вектор тогда.

Comment: Атрибут не сработал

Comment: Это либа d3 , она уже и так всё мает , А мне нужно докинуть некоторые элементы

Comment: Наконец-то сделал,

Comment: Нужно было патерну дать ширину и высоту 1 , и добавить patternUnits - objectBoundingBox